# Why is there no counterpart to cf_consumed for the Clang static analyzer that marks an argument as being retained?

Tags: memory-management, clang, core-foundation, clang-static-analyzer

Say we want to create our own `CFRetain` and `CFRelease` functions, called `MyRetain` and `MyRelease`. For the latter, we can just write:

```
void MyRelease(CFTypeRef __attribute__((cf_consumed)) typeRef);
// or
void MyRelease(CFTypeRef CF_RELEASES_ARGUMENT typeRef);
```

However, for `MyRetain` it seems we're out of luck. I would have suspected something like this to exist:

```
void MyRetain(CFTypeRef __attribute__((cf_retained)) typeRef);
// or
void MyRetain(CFTypeRef CF_RETAINS_ARGUMENT typeRef);
```

Is this simply an omission? Is there maybe an alternative I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

I think the usual case would be to declare it as:

```
CF_RETURNS_RETAINED CFTypeRef MyRetain(CFTypeRef typeRef);
```

since retaining functions usually return the same value.  Release-type functions generally return void so they would have to annotate the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to use `__attribute__((cf_returns_retained))`, which is often `#define`’d as `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED`.

From the [relevant lines in the CoreFoundation source](https://github.com/opensource-apple/CF/blob/master/CFBase.h#L195):

```objc
#ifndef CF_RETURNS_RETAINED
#if __has_feature(attribute_cf_returns_retained)
#define CF_RETURNS_RETAINED __attribute__((cf_returns_retained))
#else
#define CF_RETURNS_RETAINED
#endif
#endif
```

… that file, [CFBase.h](https://github.com/opensource-apple/CF/blob/master/CFBase.h), is worth perusing – it contains many of the more obscure CF-specific `#define` and `typedef` definitions.